# Detect image selection from UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift3, uiwebview, uiimagepickercontroller

I have made a wrapper app for a website running in c#. Everything runs well until the user tries to upload an image. Permissions have been granted, it allows to select image and use camera, but it does not prevent video (from library or camera).

**How do I allow access only to images?** I cannot access the backend to modify the request, so I am looking for a solution where I can do it from the app.

Things tested and failed:

1 Detect from urlRequest the call and override it ( web view functions don't get called at all during the image selection)

2 Use UIImagePickerControllerDelegate - selectedImage function does not get called, image simply shows up in webkit as an icon after selection

3 Looked into info.plist restrictions, but there doesn't seem to be any difference between images and video from that end, they are simply camera and photo library permissions

4 Have tried `webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript`, however, looking at the source code, the method called when "Add Image" button is pressed is actually on a different page, with it's url inside one of the `script` tags. Not sure if this solution can be pursued to a result as I don't know much about web development

For (4), this is part of the source code in the body of the page :

```
<script src="...LayoutScripts?v=d2fICvYP326VZcultpCUKcJNjGj0lMG8f4XKY8-Vyks1"></script>

<script src="...jquery.validate.additionalmethods.js"></script>

<script src="...Repairs.js"></script>
```

Then the ...Repairs.js leads to an URL with a number of methods in JS, none of which seems to have a "permission" type of request for the device.

Happy to try and test any possible solutions.

Comment: You can execute a JS script from webview to modify html tag. `webview. stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementById('file').setAttribute('accept','image/*')")`

Comment: I've tried it, but in this form it doesn't work, thou I can see how it should be the solution to my problem. Do I need to replace the 'file' and 'accept' with other values that might be used in the actual script? Is there a way I can print that script in the console output to find the correct ones?

Comment: You need to replace 'file' with the id of that tag or need to use other `getElement` methods to reach the tag.

Comment: I've accessed the source code but the actual method called on button press it's inside one of the external scripts (don't know much about web developing, but it's inside script tags, one of a few, with it's own .js url), so I don't think I can access it and change values...